# JSF inputText and Sessions in jsf managed bean

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I would like to know how can i read a value of input text from the managed bean.
I know it is possible to read this way and it is very stright forward.

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{mylogin.username}" required="true" />
```

But what if lets say i have a value like

```
 <h:inputText id="username" value="some_value" required="true" />
```

And i want to read this "some_value" in my managed bean.
Is it possible ?

Another question is it possible to access to the session variables in managed bean or should i somehow pass them to there ?

Comment: In the second part of your question, are you talking about the servlet session, or session-scoped managed-beans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latter case that `some_value` is not bean managed, IMHO. Nonetheless, you can read that. Do something like this,

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request =
      (HttpServletRequest)ctx.getExternalContext().getRequest(); 
request.getParameter("username");
```

Similarly, regarding accessing session variable,

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request =
      (HttpServletRequest)ctx.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
```

Comment: The parameter name may not be "username" (see my answer); also, you can avoid casting to the servlet API if you want to.

Comment: I really like this way since it not ties bean to JSF.

Answer (score 3):

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{mylogin.username}" required="true" />
```

This would be the best way, in my opinion. Is there a reason you would like to avoid this? You can, as [harto suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905194/basic-question-about-jsf-inputtext-and-about-sessions-in-jsf-managed-bean/905380#905380), use component binding, but (as Vinegar points out) you gain nothing from this approach.

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="some_value" required="true" />
```

If you want to read the above value, it is possible to read it directly from the request parameters. The [ExternalContext](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html) encapsulates the underlying container API and can be accessed in a managed bean like so:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext
    .getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext extContext = facesContext
    .getExternalContext();
Map<String, String> params = extContext
    .getRequestParameterMap();
```

But, aside from violating the model-view-presenter contract, you can run into some practical problems. The parameter key may not be "username", but might be something like "j_id_jsp_115874224_691:username", depending on whether you make the component a child of any [NamingContainer](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html)s (like [UIForm](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIForm.html) - see the [prependId attribute](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/h/form.html)) or if the view is namespaced. Hard-coding this value anywhere is probably a bad idea. You can read about the relationship between JSF component IDs and rendered HTML IDs [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/02/jsf-working-with-component-ids.html). If you want to use [UIComponent.getClientId](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)) to generate the the key, you are back to component binding because you need to get a reference to the component.

> Another question is it possible to access to the session variables in managed bean..?

See [ExternalContext.getSessionMap](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap()).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time and explaining things to me. I really appreciate it.

The reason i asked is because JSF is first java framework i am studying and I really like it. The question was for education purpose(prior to it i tryed to goodle, but didnot find no good explanation), in reall application i am not going use it like that, but i wanted to know how it can be done.

Comment: Ah, I quite forgot about the naming issue. Thanks for pointing out. Futher dealing with Maps is a better idea. +1

Answer (score 2):

A common way to read a component value is to create a binding to the component in your managed-bean, and read the value from it.

For example:

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="some_value" required="true"
    binding="#{mylogin.usernameField}" />
```

Then, in the managed-bean:

```
private UIInput usernameField;

public void setUsernameField(UIInput usernameField) { 
    this.usernameField = usernameField;
}
public UIInput getUsernameField() { 
    return usernameField; 
}
```

Finally, to access the field value:

```
Object value = usernameField.getValue();
```

Comment: That would be component binding. Not a good idea, IMHO. Thats the reason I didn't mention it. But yes its the way. Actually in this case you lose the simplicity of POJO, and tie your bean completely with JSF.

Comment: Sure - it's not practical unless you wanted to do something else with the component. The best way to do it is well-known - just use a value binding expression.